# The size of a column in the database can slow a query?

Tags: database, postgresql, size

I have a table with a column contains HTML content and is relative greater than the other columns.

Having a column with a great size can slow the queries in this table?
I need to put this big fields in another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-toast.html) Technique should handle this for you, after  a given size the storage will be transparently set in a _toast table and some internal things are done to avoid slowing down your queries (check the given link).

But of course if you always retrieve the whole content you'll loose time in the retrieval. And it's also clear that requests on this table where this column is not used won't suffer from this column size.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the database the slower the queries. Always.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that if you have large column, there is going to be more disk I/O since caching the column itself takes more space.  However, putting these in a different table won't likely alleviate this issue (other than the issue below).  When you don't explicitly need the actual HTML data, be sure not to SELECT it.

Sometimes the ordering of the columns can matter because of the way rows are stored, if you're really worried about it, store it as the last column so it doesn't get paged when selecting other columns

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at how Postgres internally stores things to see if you need to split this out but a very large field could cause the way the data is stored on the disk to be broken up and thus adds to the time it takes to access it.

Further, returning 100 bytes of data vice 10000 bytes of data for one record is clearly going to be slower, the more records the slower. If you are doing SELECT *  this is clearly a problem espcially if you usually do not need the HTML.

Another consideration could be ptting the HTML information in a noSQL database. This kind of document information is what they excel at. No reason you can't use both a realtional database for some info and a noSQL database for other info.